# change and miss columns from text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with below data and trying to change columns and write into another file.

Here the input is

```
                            a|b|c|d|e|f
                            d|f|g|h|y|s
```

Like that i have 1000 rows

Now i want to swap the columns and also don't want all the columns and then write into another file.

The output i need is   -  I don't need 2 columns from the input

```
                c|d|a|b
                g|h|d|f
```

I tried like below and it's not working

```
      with open("old.txt","r") as file,open('new.txt', 'w') as outfile:
               freader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = '|')
                for line in file:
                line[3], line[4],line[1],line[2]
               outfile.write(line)
```

Any help is more appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean removing the last two rows and then adding first two from beginning to the end?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  "it's not working" is not a problem specification.  We expect you to narrow the problem to a single area of uncertainty: is your problem with reading the file, extracting the fields, or with writing the desired rearrangement?  Basic debugging (i.e. `print` statements) will narrow down the problem quickly.

Comment: I do note immediate problems in glancing at the code: (1) your file description shows a comma delimiter, but your `reader` specifies a bar; (2) The fields you index do not match the ones in your example.

Comment: Your code had quite a lot of flaws. I tried to explain them as best as I could, but if there is anything you still don't understand then I will explain some more. Keep learning, you'll get there!

Comment: Your code had quite a lot of flaws. I tried to explain them as best as I could, but if there is anything you still don't understand then I will explain it further. Keep learning, you'll get there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('old.csv', 'r') as f_in, open('new.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    freader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter = '|')
    fwriter = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter = '|')
    for line in freader:
        fwriter.writerow([line[2], line[3], line[0], line[1]])
```

---

File `old.csv`:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f
d|f|g|h|y|s
```

File `new.csv`:

```
c|d|a|b
g|h|d|f
```

Answer (score 0):

> `for line in file:` while this is valid syntax, you should use the cvsreader that you created. Replace this with `for line in freader:`

> `line[3], line[4],line[1],line[2]` This line does nothing, you should store it in a variable. Replace this with `newline = line[2] + "|" + line[3] + "|" + line[0] + "|" + line[1]`. This builds a string with `|` in between each character.

> `outfile.write(line)` You are writing the same line that you read. Replace this with `outfile.write(newline + "\n")`. This will write the string we created to the file. Adding `\n` will add a newline at the end of each line

```
with open("old.txt","r") as file,open('new.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    freader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = '|')
    for line in freader:
        newline = line[2] + "|" + line[3] + "|" + line[0] + "|" + line[1]
        outfile.write(newline + "\n")
```